# Warning/Error message when asking for file path with handle.exe in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the file path assosciated with microsoft word and for this I use the following PowerShell script, I am also using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle

```
.\handle.exe -p winword | Select-String File
```

But instead of getting the paths I am getting this message

```
Please be aware that, similar to other debug tools that capture “process state” information, 
files saved by Sysinternals tools may include personally identifiable or other sensitive 
information(such as usernames, passwords, paths to files accessed, and paths to registry 
accessed).By using this software, you acknowledge that you are aware of this and take sole 
responsibility for any personally identifiable or other sensitive information provided 
Microsoft or any other party through your use of the software.
```

Can anyone please explain how to go around this, thanks.

Comment: that is the notice that the exe shows when the user agreement has not been accepted. [*grin*] ///// also, WHY do you expect a non-powershell exe to output objects? ///// also also, if you simply want the path the app was loaded from ... why don't you use powershell to get that? take a look at `(Get-Process -Name firefox).Path` [replace the `firefox` with your app name].

Comment: I understood now that this problem was due to not accepting user agreement //// I expect it to do that because thats what it is supposed to do and that is what it does //// I do not simply want what you are saying I want to get the path of file currently being edited for example a file being edited on Microsoft Word

Comment: @AmmarHassan answer your own question if this is resolved.

Comment: @AmmarHassan - aha! thank you for the clarification ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the user agreement was not accepted for the exe file, so I ran just `.\handle.exe` and it prompted to agree the user agreement after that `.\handle.exe -p winword | Select-String File` worked